# formatNumber is not defined

Tags: javascript, object, module, undefined

The piece of code causing me trouble is in the UI controller:

```
addListItem: function(obj, type) {
      var html, newHtml, element;
      // Create HTML string with placeholder text
      
      if (type === 'inc') {
          element = DOMStrings.incomeContainer;
          
          html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="inc-%id%"> <div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
      } else if (type === 'exp') {
          element = DOMStrings.expensesContainer;
          
          html = '<div class="item clearfix" id="exp-%id%"><div class="item__description">%description%</div><div class="right clearfix"><div class="item__value">%value%</div><div class="item__percentage">21%</div><div class="item__delete"><button class="item__delete--btn"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline"></i></button></div></div></div>';
      }
      
      // Replace the placeholder text with some actual data
      newHtml = html.replace('%id%', obj.id);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%description%', obj.description);
      newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', formatNumber(obj.value));
      
      // Insert the HTML into the DOM
      document.querySelector(element).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', newHtml);
    },

    getDomStrings: function() {
      return DOMStrings
    }
```

It keeps saying formatNumber is not defined, but I honestly can't find what is causing the error.

Comment: Probably what's causing the error is that `formatNumber()` is not defined. What do you expect that to be?

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceError: formatNumber is not defined

The error means that you are referencing something that is not defined. In this case you are referecing `formatNumber` on line 98, which is not declared.

You have to either create the function, or remove the code which is using it.

This line: `newHtml = newHtml.replace('%value%', formatNumber(obj.value));`